# Hover на объект и отображение кнопки three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Есть объекты на сцене, при на ведении на один из объектов хочу отобразить так сказать "меню", а точнее кнопку на подложке, при нажатии на нее выполнять те или иные действия для этого объекта.
Всезнающий гугл выдал [пример](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Tooltip.html) но здесь как tooltip, и это совсем не то(
Возможно ли это? Как? Или пример где то. Спасибо.

```
if (intersects.length) {
    var intersect = intersects[0].object;
    //TODO: ....
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrAndrew/8mzak8y6/4/)

Comment: А где должна располагаться обозначенная "кнопка на подложке"? И когда она должна появляться: сразу при перемещении мыши над объектом или по правому клику мышки? Можно каких-то поясняющих картинок?

Comment: Думал так что бы, при наведении идет некоторая задержка 200-300 миллисекунд и появлялась http://joxi.ru/5mdYNgOFkzZZb2 просто сверху, или снизу, так как эти объекты я двигаю мышью по сцене. После клика левой кнопкой, на это "меню" оно пропадает, так как событие идет уже на движение(mousemove) По правому клику мышью не думал...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это скорее концепт и отправная точка. Поэтому финальная реализация может радикально отличаться от того, что представлено здесь.

Если мышь по-над объектом - по правому щелчку выскакивает меню с кнопкой. При нажатии на кнопку - меняется цвет объекта, меню скрывается.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 50);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry(10, 2, 100, 20);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00
});
var torusKnot = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(torusKnot);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

/////////////////////////////

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var intersect;
var rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();

window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
window.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
} else {
  document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function () {
    window.event.returnValue = false;
  });
}


function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  mouse.x = ((event.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -((event.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height) * 2 + 1;

}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var rightclick;
    if (!event) var event = window.event;
    if (event.which) rightclick = (event.which == 3);
    else if (event.button) rightclick = (event.button == 2);
  if (!rightclick) return;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([torusKnot]);

  if (intersects.length) {
    intersect = intersects[0].object;
    menu.style.left = (event.clientX - rect.left) + "px";
    menu.style.top = (event.clientY - rect.top) + "px";
    menu.style.display = "";
  }
  else{
    intersect = undefined;
  }
}

changeColor.addEventListener("click", function(){
 intersect.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0x777777 + 0x777777);
  menu.style.display = "none";
}, false);

function onWindowResize(event) {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="menu" style="position:absolute;display:none;background-color:red">
  <span color="red">Меню</span>
  <br>
  <button id="changeColor">
    Сменить цвет
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Хоть это и не при hover как в теме, это действительно хороший концепт и отправная точка! Спасибо тебе prisoner849!

Comment: @Mr.Andrew Рад помочь )